# How to take off the marks of a graphic made with a CSV file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm importing a CSV file and I want to take off the marks of the graphic,how can I do this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

%\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented out dataCL.csv is not overwriten.
\begin{filecontents*}{dataCL.csv}
    x, y
    1, 10
    2, 15
    3, 17
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [mark = none, draw = none,col sep=comma,x=x, y=y] {dataCL.csv};
\end{axis}
asdfasdfasdfasd
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Also, it is better to not use the `minimal` class, so I'd recommend switching to `article`: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided). Thanks for providing a MWE, but it would be helpful if you also provided some data points as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... 
I'm sorry if that's isn't the best way to provide a data file, but anyway here it is. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij82237ae500fiq/dataCL.csv

Comment: You should minimze the amount of data to what is required to reproduce the problem. I have updated the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). If you prefer to use your data please edit it but only enough points so that the problem is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mark=none` is an option to `\addplot`/`\addplot+`, not to `table`. BTW, you should use `only marks` instead of `draw=none`. Please find attached an example in which the first plot has only a line and the second one has only marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}% Commented out dataCL.csv is not overwriten.
\begin{filecontents*}{dataCL.csv}
    x, y
    1, 10
    2, 15
    3, 17
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [mark=none] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y] {dataCL.csv};
    \addplot+ [only marks] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y] {dataCL.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also omit the `x=x` and `y=y` parts, which are redundant

Comment: I should have though of that!! But, if you are updating this, I'd also recommend you use two separate `tikzpicture`s (or a third column in the data) so as to make the graph clear. Took me time to see that this is actually producing the desired output (initially it seems as if it is not).